# Error: System.InvalidOperationException in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to enter some data into database and get access_token on the end of successful call.

When I make a call passing this parameters:

[image]

Everything goes fine, user gets registered and saved into database, and access_token returns to user:

[image]

But, when I add signs +, = or \ in the deviceId value I get exception and nothing get saved in database:

[image]

[image]

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.InputStream'.",
    "exceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
    "stackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeDictionary(JsonWriter writer, IDictionary values, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeDictionary(JsonWriter writer, IDictionary values, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__13.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "Timeouts are not supported on this stream.",
        "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
        "stackTrace": "   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()\r\n   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.DelegatingStream.get_ReadTimeout()\r\n   at GetReadTimeout(Object )\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)"
    }
}
```

This is model definition for this call:

```
public class Registration
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password{ get; set; }
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    }
```

Field deviceId gets saved into database as UserName, and by it's definition it is NVARCHAR(1024)

[image]

Is it possible that NVARCHAR doesn't allow characters that are not letters and numbers? Did someone else had problem like this?

EDIT: This is the method where the problem is:

```
[Route("registration/request")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RegistrationRequest(Registration model)
{
    try
    {
        MatrixLogManager.Info("Starting token creating.");

        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var tokenServiceUrl = request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + request.ApplicationPath + "/Token";

        MatrixLogManager.Info("Checking if model is valid.");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(BadRequest(ModelState));
        }
        using (MatrixServiceLayerLogin login = new MatrixServiceLayerLogin())
        {
            if (login.LoginUser(model.UserName, model.Password, true, true))
            {
                var personId = login.GetPersonId();

                MatrixLogManager.Debug("User " + model.UserName + "successfully logged in on MatrixSTS.");
                try
                {
                    using (var authRepo = new AuthRepository())
                    {
                        ApplicationUser appUser = new UserFactory().CreateApplicationUser(model, personId);
                        IdentityResult result = await authRepo.RegisterUser(appUser);
                        EMailService.SendEmail(appUser);
                        IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

                        if (errorResult != null)
                        {
                            return Request.CreateResponse(errorResult);
                        }

                        using (var client = new HttpClient())
                        {
                            var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                                                {
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", appUser.UserName),
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "0000")
                                                };

                            var requestParamsFormUrlEncoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams);
                            var tokenServiceResponse = await client.PostAsync(tokenServiceUrl, requestParamsFormUrlEncoded);
                            var responseString = await tokenServiceResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            var responseCode = tokenServiceResponse.StatusCode;
                            var responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(responseCode)
                            {
                                Content = new StringContent(responseString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                            };

                            responseMsg.Headers.Add("PSK", appUser.PSK);
                            return responseMsg;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MatrixLogManager.Error("Error: ", ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MatrixLogManager.Error(string.Format("Error while trying registring user: Exception = {0} InnerException {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException.Message));
        throw;
    }
}
```

Try-Catch does not catch any exception, the real exception happens here:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(ApplicationUser userModel)
{
    userModel.TwoFactorEnabled = true;
    userModel.PSK = TimeSensitivePassCode.GeneratePresharedKey();

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userModel, "0000");

    return result;
}
```

When the line where the result is returns to client. I've gues that saving in line before doesn't go well. I will set try-catch in that part of code and I will post exception.

Comment: The title and text of the question are completely unrelated. What is the actual question? Where is the controller code that produces this error? Anyway, NVARCHAR is Unicode - it even allows Chinese characters

Comment: Also debug the application and post the actual stack trace, not an image or a flattened text in Json. The stack trace is undreadable in this form.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for answering... I wasn't sure how to name this or how to call this problem... The question would be: What is the possible reason for this behavior? And how to solve it...Why those sings make problems...

Comment: Post the code. Debug it and post the contents of the exception, including the stack trace. Otherwise we can only guess. MY guess is, you are trying to return an Entity Framework object that uses lazy loading but I can't read the stack trace

Comment: This has nothing to do with the database. this Is to do with the data being posted. this will be to do with certain characters meaning something else. i.e an '=' in a cookie is a separator.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that the try-catch doesn't catch this exception, it simply stops...and send the message I've posted. I've posted in the post what happens when I use debugger.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Do you maybe know what is the best way for work around for this problem?

Answer (score 7):

This usually happens when you're wrapping a Response twice.

Consider your method returns `Task<IHttpActionResult>` instead of `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and note how you are wrapping that `errorResult` twice when calling:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(errorResult);
```

this is probably leading you to believe that errors in your token service are causing this issue, when the double-wrapping in fact is   :)

consider the following:

```
[Route("registration/request")]
public async Task<IHttpResult> RegistrationRequest(Registration model)
{
    try
    {
        MatrixLogManager.Info("Starting token creating.");

        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var tokenServiceUrl = request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + request.ApplicationPath + "/Token";

        MatrixLogManager.Info("Checking if model is valid.");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        using (MatrixServiceLayerLogin login = new MatrixServiceLayerLogin())
        {
            if (login.LoginUser(model.UserName, model.Password, true, true))
            {
                var personId = login.GetPersonId();

                MatrixLogManager.Debug("User " + model.UserName + "successfully logged in on MatrixSTS.");
                try
                {
                    using (var authRepo = new AuthRepository())
                    {
                        ApplicationUser appUser = new UserFactory().CreateApplicationUser(model, personId);
                        IdentityResult result = await authRepo.RegisterUser(appUser);
                        EMailService.SendEmail(appUser);
                        IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

                        if (errorResult != null)
                        {
                            // MAJOR CHANGE here
                            return errorResult;
                        }

                        using (var client = new HttpClient())
                        {
                            var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                                                {
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", appUser.UserName),
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "0000")
                                                };

                            var requestParamsFormUrlEncoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams);
                            var tokenServiceResponse = await client.PostAsync(tokenServiceUrl, requestParamsFormUrlEncoded);
                            var responseString = await tokenServiceResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            var responseCode = tokenServiceResponse.StatusCode;
                            var responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(responseCode)
                            {
                                Content = new StringContent(responseString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                            };

                            responseMsg.Headers.Add("PSK", appUser.PSK);
                            return responseMsg;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MatrixLogManager.Error("Error: ", ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MatrixLogManager.Error(string.Format("Error while trying registring user: Exception = {0} InnerException {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException.Message));
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: `This usually happens when you're wrapping a Response twice.` Bingo!

Answer (score 1):

I cant see your full implementation, but if I were take an educated guess, you are likely trying to call your login routine, which returns a HttpResponseMessage data type (from within your Register routine). And both of these methods make use of Request.CreateResponse to create the response.

See the problem is, that you are trying to serialize an already serialized HttpResponseMessage. Your Login method will call Request.CreateResponse to create the HttpResponseMessage which you probably just turn around and "pass-through" to your Register method (but are likely funneling it through another Request.CreateResponse method call --- which is where you get into trouble). IT is an "implicit" mistake and tough to catch - something like a chess player staring at the chess board for hours.

Now for the solution:
simply pass the result of your login method as the result of your register method without "processing" it through the Request.CreateResponse method. If you are a purist of Rest returned status codes, you can change the returned status code first prior to returning the Register method (because Login is likely to have a status code of OK [200] - whereas it is better practice to return CREATED [201] in the Register rest end point).